# JTable Repaint Parent from a Pop-Up

Tags: jquery, jtable, repaint

Got a popup that used to do the below javascript function when closed.

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
       window.parent.location.reload();
</script>
```

However, all I need to do on my parent is refresh/repaint the JTable that is hooked on a div tag named site.

```
$('#Site').jtable({
```

I tried:

```
window.parent.$('#Site').repaint();

// and

window.parent.location.$('#Site').repaint();

// and

parent.$('#Site').jtable('repaint');
```

However, nothing refresh the data. I need to refresh the JTable since there was several back-end changes that happened that I can not keep track of.

Just wondering if there is a way to reloaded the data in the JTable.

Comment: If you are updating the table, you need to trigger the correct model event to have the changes displayed in the table. Calling repaint wont do anything for you. Are you using a custom table model?

Comment: I am just using jquery and jtable. No other modules. I am trying to refresh the table due to an event that happened outside of jtable that was done. I am looking for it to re-read the list and reload/repaint the view.

Comment: Yes, all that is presented in your post. My comment is still accurate, and updating the table model is the solution you need.